# How to replace PDF download button with a Print button?

Tags: pdf, button, printing, download, nopcommerce

I'm using NopCommerce 4.6.
In Admin > Sales > Orders > Single order, there is a button for Invoice (PDF). By clicking on this button, it downloads the Invoice for the specific single order.

Is there a way to convert that Button into a printing one (ctrl+p)? Or, force browser to open a pdf in the new tab (with the url, so it is easily printable, instead of downloading each pdf one by one and opening them to print).

`<a asp-action="PdfInvoice" asp-route-orderId="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-info"> <i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i> @T("Admin.Orders.PdfInvoice") </a>`

This is the line of code attached to that button.

Thank you!

I tried using Chat GPT, no luck for now.